# Does cCXF support REST services?

Tags: web-services, rest, esb, routes, talend

I have created two REST services with Talend Open Studio for ESB V5.2, the first one gets a XML file (POST) and returns the same file as a response, the second one inserts this file into a database. I want to create a route to connect these two REST services but I don't know how. Usualy we use the component cCXF for web services SOAP, what about REST?

Answer (score 0):

Not really cCXF, but Talend Open Studio for ESB does have REST support. See this tutorial: **[How to create a REST service](http://www.talendforge.org/tutorials/tutorial.php?language=english&idTuto=104)**.

Quote:

> In this tutorial, you will see how to build your first simple REST data service in both **Talend Open Studio for ESB** and Talend Enterprise ESB Studio by using Talend ESB REST components and the new tXMLMap component.

There are REST components in the palette:

> In the Palette to the right:
>
> To add the REST service components, search "**REST**" in the **Find component...** field and press Enter.
> The **tRESTRequest** and **tRESTResponse** components needed to create the service provider are displayed under the **ESB > REST** folder.

[image: REST components in the Palette]

Comment: Thank you acdcjunior for your anwser. I have already created two REST services using the tRESTRequest and tRESTResponse components, my question is how to create a mediation route to send a message from the first REST service to the second one. cCXF is used to create routes for SOAP services, it requires wsdlURL in its configuration but what about REST ?